# How to make a listener of a service on android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have this code to check if a service is active, but I would like to know if there is any way for an EditText to show the status of the service, without making this query per second, or in a separate thread, or linking it in some way? that it is possible to detect if the service stopped

```
private bool MiServicioEstaCorriendo(Class @class, Context contexto)
        {
            ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)contexto.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
            foreach (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service in manager.GetRunningServices(Integer.MaxValue))
            {
                if (@class.Name.Equals(service.Service.ClassName))
                {
                    Log.Info(typeof(BroadcastGps).Name, "MiServcicioEstaCorriendo: true");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            Log.Info(typeof(BroadcastGps).Name, "MiServcicioEstaCorriendo: false");
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: What is the service? How do you judge the service active or not?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically in need of a way to pass events/messages among classes within your application. So this question probably goes down to Android & C# implementation of such a pattern. Xamarin.Forms has a [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) class, but since you are using Xamarin.Native, you would have to create something yourself

There's nothing actually already baked in to Android or C#, but so you can implement one of the most common ways to let a class spread an event/message using the "Listener" (term used in Android) or "[Delegate](https://codewithshadman.com/publish-subscribe-design-pattern-in-csharp/)" (term used in C#) technique.

There are frameworks too like [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/xamarin-android-c-sharp/data-streams-publish-and-subscribe-sdk-v3) that you can use as Nuget packages that simplify everything for you.

Some more resources to understand the concept: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07265/index.html).
And Some Android resources: [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [Parcelables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html).

Don't forget that your event to update your EditText may not be fired on the Main UIThread so you won't be able to see the changes unless you force that update line to be Run on UI Thread.